How can i make the body occupy the entire screen?
enter image description here
this is my css for reference
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    * {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}


* {
    font-family: 'Poppins', monospace;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

Im trying to add a gradient background, but it does not seem to occupy the entire screen, can someone please help?

Do you know about the CSS height property?

Please give more complete CSS with the relevant HTML. Where is the gradient bg?

simply activate full-screen mode. (F11 on keyboards)

As said by someone else, body { min-height: 100vh } will by default size the height to cover the screen fully. However, it is an incomplete answer and misses a few steps.

Add body { min-height: 100vh; }
You will see that the body will vertically overflow. This is caused by the default margin of the body which equals for most browsers 0.5em (8px). This needs to be reset with: body { margin: 0; }
The content will now be directly on the edges of the viewport making the content harder to read. Therefore either padding has to be added or all content of the body needs a margin: body { padding: 0.5em; }
The body will overflow again because of the default box model. YOu can fix this with a global reset: * { box-sizing: border-box; }



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

/* for visualization purpose only */
body {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}



